# What is the probability two subsets of a given one intersects?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $A$, with cardinality $n(A)=a$, and two subsets $B$ and $C$ of $A$, with cardinalities $n(B)=b$, $n(C)=c$, how can I deduce the formula for the probability that $B$ and $C$ intersects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $B\subseteq A$ such that $|B|=b$, the subsets of $A$ that *don’t* intersect $B$ are the subsets of $A\setminus B$; $\binom{a-b}c$ of these have cardinality $c$. There are altogether $\binom{a}c$ subsets of $A$ of cardinality $c$, so given $B$, the probability that a randomly chosen subset of $A$ of cardinality $c$ *does* intersect $B$ is

$$1-\frac{\binom{a-c}c}{\binom{a}c}\;.$$

Since this is the case for each $B\subseteq A$ of cardinality $b$, it is the desired probability.

Comment: It makes  sense. Thank you!

Comment: @user392404: You’re welcome!